# Strange issue when launching device Settings from app

Tags: android

So I run my app on Android 5.0 and 6.0.
In my app there is a button in a Fragment that opens device settings and goes to Location screen:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

After the Settings screen is launched, I press the HOME button and I go to the device home screen.

Then I press the app icon to open the application and here is the problem:

In Android 5.0 I see the fragment that launched the settings screen.

In Android 6.0 I see the settings screen. I need to press the back button to return to my Fragment.

The desired behaviour is the one that happens in Android 5.0.
The settings screen should not be counted as the "last" screen that the app used.

Another important point, I'm not entirely sure the issues is due to different Android versions. The desired behaviour occurs on Samsung devices and the bad behaviour occurs on Nexus devices. Maybe its related to that.

Is there any way to resolve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

to solve this issue. The device settings screen is not added to history stack so I always return to the right activity.